# For loop syntax for ES6 when only length size available

Tags: javascript

I have value X that's supposed to be the "length" of what my loop should be (for example):

```
length = 10
```

I need to run a for loop to run `length` times. there's no object/array/anything I run on, nothing beyond the reference value `length`. is there a better way or cleaner way to write a for loop or to create a loop that runs `length` times in ES6 than this?

```
for(let i = 0; i < length ; i++)
```

Comment: What's not "better" about that?

Comment: I am asking if there's a more advanced way to write a for loop in ES6 based on this circumstance. If this is the best available syntax, perfect.

Comment: You could make it more "advanced" if you dynamically (or even lazily) generate a sequence to loop over...but I wouldn't call it *better*.

Comment: `for(let i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)` you save one variable -

Comment: @GrafiCode `while(length--)` is even shorter, if `i` is unneeded. And assuming `length` is never going to be negative (or you get an infinite loop)

Answer (score 2):

An elegant way would be a generator for the indices:

```
  function* range(from, to) {
    for(let i = from; i < to; i++)
       yield i;
  }

 for(const i of range(0, length)) /*...*/
```

But that's overengineering. A simple for loop is fine.

Comment: `But that's overengineering` naaa xD

Comment: @grafiCode well, in languages with infix notation and operator overloading that's quite useful, e.g. `for(i in 0 until length step 2)` (Kotlin). But in JS the benefits are quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a strictly more elegant solution to that. You could write it like this

```
new Array(length).forEach(() => {
  // do something
})
```

but if that's a more elegant solution is a matter of opinion.